# Changing the status as compelted in a cell once the macro is completed

Tags: vba, excel

How to run a macro based on a status from a cell

and

How to change or update a cell once the macro is completed

Comment: You could use an event-triggered macro to run it; just write to the cell when you are done.  You should know that SO is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options on how you can run a macro when status is changed in a cell, here is one of them:

To start, use `Worksheet_Change` sub. Everytime something is changed in your worksheet, this sub is triggered. You can then check if the changed cell is the one you want to check i.e. lets say your 'Status' cell is `A1`. You can use the following condition:

```
If Target.Range("A1") = Range("A1") Then
```

If it is, you can then either have your code in here or call your `macro/function/sub` from here. Once the execution of code is complete, before your `End If`, you can now update the required cell i.e. lets say the cell you want to update to indicate that the macro is complete is `B1`. Simply do this:

```
Range("B1").Value = "Macro complete"
```